# Why aren't properties injected by Spring into LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following config class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:my.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.my.data.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyDataConfig {

    /* ... */

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        /* ... */
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(Oracle10gDialect.class.getName());
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.FORMAT_SQL, false);
        properties.put(AvailableSettings.USE_SQL_COMMENTS, false);
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        return transactionManager;
    }

    // WORKS
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter, Properties jpaProperties) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.my.data.model");
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
    }

    // DOES NOT WORK
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.my.data.model");
        // FIXME Spring should inject, shouldn't it?
        // entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        // entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
    }
```

}

I don't get why I have to provide beans to `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` (see last 2 methods' differences) while I don't have to for the others beans:

- datasource is auto-wired into `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`;
- anything (datasource, entityManagerFactory, jpaDialect...) is auto-wired into `JpaTransactionManager`.

Or maybe I don't fully get the Spring *magic*...

Thanks.

PS: the `/* ... */` comments hide some cumbersome `@Value("${...}"} private String xxx;` fields as well as setting those to Datasource (like driver class, url, user, password, etc.)

Comment: Nothing is autowired... Check the source code, things get deduced from what has been injected into the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Also you should simply return the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` from the method and not call `getObject()` and `afterPropertiesSet` let Spring handle that for you. And no spring should not inject those... Imagine 3 factories and 5 datasources what should be injected into what?! You have to tell spring to inject something. I you want auto configuration use Spring Boot and not plain spring.

Comment: I know about Spring Boot, but it has too much dependencies (including a whole web server) and so much configuration is hidden behind the scene, so I'm not interested in it. Btw did you actually read my entire question? See the list, I'm talking about HibernateJpaVendorAdapter or JpaTransactionManager whose @Bean annoted methods are called BEFORE entityManagerFactory().

Comment: And finally, if I don't call ``afterPropertiesSet()``  + return ``getObject()`` I get this exception when Spring tries to instantiate a bean called ``jpaContext`` (class: ``org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.DefaultJpaContext``):
``org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}``

Comment: They aren't called before the `EntityManagerFactory` trust me. If you get that exception you have something wrong in your setup. And your understanding of Spring Boot is wrong it doesn't include a web server it only includes that if you want it to. Also the fact that beans are created before something doesn't mean they are fully initialized, there are callback methods which are called. As stated look at the sources.

Comment: _it doesn't include a web server it only includes that if you want it to_
oh really? doesn't seem to be the first thing that's told, see https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start or https://app.updateimpact.com/treeof/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.4.2.RELEASE

Comment: Well correct and that is because it is told to include that as it is part of `spring-boot-starter-web` so it is a web application which needs a servlet container. If you don't include that and only use, for instance `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` then there is no servlet container.

Comment: And there is no ``spring-web``/``spring-webmvc`` in ``spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`` either. I don't get your answer.
Plus I don't like the fact I have to inherit from a given **parent** artifact, as well as there's CLI in my app. It's a **web** app after all.
See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/pom.xml

Comment: You don't have to inherit from a parent you can use it as an import in the `dependencyManagement` section as well. Instead of making assumptions check/challenge those assumptions. If you don't include tomcat (either directly or through `spring-boot-starter-web` then there is no web server). Spring Boot detects what is on your classpath and based on that makes guesses on what you want to start.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/pom.xml
``<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  </dependency>``

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/pom.xml ``<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>``

Comment: So basically if you import ``spring-boot-starter-web`` you transitively import ``spring-boot-starter-tomcat`` which imports ``tomcat-embed-core``, ``tomcat-embed-el`` and ``tomcat-embed-websocket``. I don't get why/how it is an _assumption_.

Comment: Your initial statement (and assumption) was that Spring Boot by default required including a servlet container. That isn't the case, the same for extending the parent you don't have to there are multiple ways (all of them documented).